# OCX control: Sub New() is not accessible in this context because it is 'Private'

Tags: vb.net, vb6, activex, com-interop, vb6-migration

Recently I've been trying to create an activeX control and use it in some vb.net code. After much struggle i created my control in vb6 and generated the ocx file. I've been trying to use it as shown in microsoft docs [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/315847/how-to-use-activex-components-in-visual-basic-net-or-in-visual-basic-2) but to no avail.
On :

```
myActiveX = New MyActiveXComponent.MyClass()
```

i keep getting

> MyActiveXComponent.MyClass.Private Sub New() is not accessible in
>   this context because it is 'Private'

I can import it to toolbox and use that way but i would prefer not to, im using visual studio 2005. Also i have an ocx which to my supprise i can use both ways(not mine) so i suspect there's something wrong with mine, but i can't figure out what.

Comment: It looks like you are creating an instance if class called `MyClass`.  Is this a class you have defined in your ocx?

Comment: @tcarvin Yes trying to instance an user control in this case MyClass which is contained in the ocx, you can find the source code here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/315847/how-to-use-activex-components-in-visual-basic-net-or-in-visual-basic-2.

Comment: Is your `Sub New` private?  Perhaps it needs to be `Public`?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I can't write sub new in vb6 at all, as far as i know New should be inside wrapper generated by interop, and it is looking at object browser, but its inhered from System.Object, where in the other working ocx it's a member of the class, almost as it was a class module.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing Classes and Controls up a bit.  But in any case, if you want your class to be publicly creatable you need to set the Instancing, and I suggest using MultiUse.

[image: Properties]

Comment: `Class`es in OCX projects are `PublicNotCreatable` by default.